# React change string to component (multiple)

Tags: regex, string, reactjs

I want to make custom grammar like Wiki and how can I do it in React and without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

For example:

"hello this is simple string [linkToSomewhere] {this is where bold goes}"

becomes

```
<div>
  hello this is simple string <Link where="linktoSomewhere"/> <Bold string="this is where bold goes"/>
</div>
```

like this

I found way to parse custom markdown to array but found no way to insert it as react component array is like

```
link[0] = "linkToSomewhere"
bold[0] = "this is where Bold goes"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should probably share the "parse custom markdown to array" approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few Markdown libraries available for React. Check out:

- react-markdown: https://rexxars.github.io/react-markdown/
- react-remarkable: https://github.com/acdlite/react-remarkable

And here's a whole host of other libraries that can translate your Markdown document into a nicely rendered HTML: https://react.rocks/tag/Markdown

And in order to learn the Markdown syntax, there are a few cheat sheets available, such as:

- http://assemble.io/docs/Cheatsheet-Markdown.html
- https://guides.github.com/pdfs/markdown-cheatsheet-online.pdf